# Testing react component - TypeError: data.map is not a function

Tags: reactjs, sinon, chai, jestjs, enzyme

I have a react component that takes an array of objects and maps them into another react component in the view. 
I am having a hard luck while testing it as it gives this error:

> TypeError: data.map is not a function

Here's the test i wrote. Notice i a passing the data prop which i believe should make it work?

**content.test.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow, mount } from 'enzyme';
import { expect } from 'chai';

import Content from '../components/Content.jsx';

describe('<Content />', () => {
  const data = {
    created: '2017-02-21T09:50:21.441815Z',
    duration: 1575,
    final_script: 'some script',
    language: 'en-GB',
    rating: 2,
    url: 'some url',
  };
  it('renders without exploding', () => {
    mount(<Content data={ data } />);
  });
});
```

and here's there component itself

**content.jsx**

```
function Content(props) {
  const { data } = props;
  return (
    <div className='content_container'>
      {
        data.map((content, index) => <AudioBox data={ content } key={ 
index } />)
      }
    </div>
  );
}

Content.propTypes = {
  data: React.PropTypes.arrayOf(React.PropTypes.object),
};

export default Content;
```

and here's the component which calls this Content component

**home.jsx**

```
class Home extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      content: null,
    };
    this.logout = this.logout.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('i2x_token');
    const requestURL = API_CONTENT;
    const requestObj = {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: new Headers({
        Authorization: `JWT ${token}`,
      }),
    };
    request(requestURL, requestObj).then((reply) => {
      if (reply.results.length > 0) {
        this.setState({ content: reply.results });
      } else {
        console.log('no reply from API');
      }
    });
  }

  logout() {
    localStorage.removeItem('i2x_token');
    browserHistory.push('/');
  }

  render() {
    const data = this.state.content;
    return (
      <div className='container'>
        <Header logout={ this.logout } />
        { data !== null &&
        <Content data={ this.state.content } />
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Home;
```

What's wrong here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think `data` that you are setting is not an `array`, because of that you are getting the error.

Check this:

```js
let data = {};

data.map(el => console.log(el))
```

Make sure that **data should be an array**, you can put the check also, before using `map` by `Array.isArray`, like this:

```
Array.isArray(data) && data.map((content, index) => <AudioBox data={content} key={index} />
```

**Try this:**

Define the data in this way:

```
const data = [
     {
        created: '2017-02-21T09:50:21.441815Z',
        duration: 1575,
        final_script: 'some script',
        language: 'en-GB',
        rating: 2,
        url: 'some url',
    }
];
```

Comment: Thanks! you're right data isn't an array. Silly me!